# Finding Corresponding data and Copying it to another sheet (Formula or VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Below you will see two screenshots. The first one has a matrix with datas highlighted in the middle. I was able to get a VBA macro from people here in SO to copy those highlighted values and paste it in a new sheet in vertical order (The highlighted values are highlighted using conditional formatting in this case it's showing values < or = 50). That's the second screenshot showing the highlighted values pasted in vertical order. Now my issue is that I need to find the corresponding SAP# to those highlighted values (Screenshot 1) and then paste it in vertical order next to the Distance column (screenshot 2). Notice there is a SAP# column and an SAP# row. I'll need both these SAP #'s corresponding to the highlighted value. I have tried using INDEX-MATCH but I got wrong answers and I'm not an expert in `For Next` coding so I couldn't even write any code.

Would love some help in this issue. FYI this is just a small sample from my large data set. I have hundreds of columns and rows. And Here's the code that I used for copying the data:

```
Sub CopyConditionalData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Location Analysis")         ' change as needed
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Output")                    ' change as needed

    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = ws1.Range("E5:ZZ200")                  'change as needed

    Dim aRng As Variant
    aRng = rRng

    Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long
    For lCols = 1 To rRng.Columns.Count
        For lRows = LBound(aRng) To UBound(aRng)
            If aRng(lRows, lCols) <= ws1.Range("D1") Then
                ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = aRng(lRows, lCols)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ws2.Select

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Seems like you should be modifying your existing code to do this, in which case you should include it in your question.

Comment: I've provided the code. And this code is courtesy of @ScottHoltzman, I've only made some small changes to it so that it works for my workbook. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I see which complicates this is the additional data you want to bring over is outside of your array: it will be easier to pick up the data starting at A1 and then adjust the starting point on your For loops.

Also there are no column/row headers visible on your screenshot which makes it a bit trickier for me to map out positions.

Untested - adjust to suit:

```
Sub CopyConditionalData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Location Analysis")         ' change as needed
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Output")                    ' change as needed

    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = ws1.Range("A1:ZZ200") '<< ##note now starting from A1##

    Dim aRng As Variant
    aRng = rRng.Value

    Dim lRows As Long, lCols As Long
    '##adjust the loop start points to mimic E5##
    For lCols = 5 To UBound(aRng, 2)
        For lRows = 5 To UBound(aRng, 1)
            If aRng(lRows, lCols) <= ws1.Range("D1") Then
                With ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Value = aRng(lRows, lCols)
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = aRng(lRows, 2) 'from ColB
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = aRng(1, lCols) 'row1 ?
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ws2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @SOreadytohelp Sir your are a genius! This code worked perfectly! The only change was .Offset(0,2).Value = aRng(2,Cols) because the horizontal SAP#'s were in row 2 but there was no way of you knowing because my screenshot didn't show it. But anyway you are amazing!! :D